# How can I generate the Core Data accessor class files (.m/.h files) from an NSManagedObjectModel at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSManagedObjectModel that I can generate at runtime but can't use it at runtime because I need the class files for the entities.

How can I generate these classes, and maybe stick them in an NSBundle to load them at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to add Protocols.
You do not need the implementation for the managed object class.

```
@protocol NSManagedObjectProtocol <NSObject>
//Add NSManagedObject methods here. Like:
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
@end

@protocol Person <NSManagedObjectProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *birthDate;
@end
```

Use the protocol to access your objects.
This code would exist in some kind of manager:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //Get the context.
NSError *error = nil;
id<Person> p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[p setName:@"PersonName"];
if ([context save:&error]) {
    //Handle error
}
```

Comment: Guess that makes sense. The rest of my app is implemented using set____: selectors like this anyway! Thanks :)